# Numerical upper and lower bounds for roots of $t^3-t(a^2+b^2+c^2)+2abc=0$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Denote with $t_1$, $t_2$, $t_3\in\mathbb C$ the roots of
$$t^3-t(a^2+b^2+c^2)+2abc=0$$
where $a,b,c\in[-1,1]$. To solve this equation is very difficult (impossible?) but is it possible to determine numerical upper and lower bounds for $|t_1|$, $|t_2|$, $|t_3|$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the roots are real, they are the eigenvalues of the symmetric real matrix 
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -a & -b \\
-a & 0 & -c \\
-b & -c & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

You may bound the eigenvalues by various [operator norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Induced_norm), either the induced $L_1$ or $L^\infty$ norm tells you that
$$ |t_j| \leq \max \{ |a| + |b|, |a| + |c|, |b| + | c|  \} $$

If one of the letters is $0,$ the matrix has a $0$ eigenvalue. If not,
the inverse is
$$
\frac{1}{2abc} \; \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
c^2 & -bc & -ca \\
-bc & b^2 & -ab \\
-ca & -ab & a^2
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and bounds on these eigenvalues, in reciprocal, give lower bounds on the original absolute values.